# Pronunciation of würden

Tags: pronunciation

I've got the idea of werden, würden, wurden etc. However, my German teacher pronounces würden like wurden, which I believe is wrong as I have listened to German singers say it differently. How is it correctly pronounced?

Comment: [ˈvʏʁdn̩](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%C3%BCrden). What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @CarstenS I pretty much knew how to pronounce it so I don't even know why I asked the question, but my main worry was what should I do when it comes to a speaking exam, and I may want to use both the conditional and passive.

Comment: "u" und "ü" are very different vowels, but not in all languages. English is very sensitive to the little pronouncation differences.

Comment: Did you mean: **German** is very sensitive to the little pronouncation differences.

Comment: For native speakers of German there is no difficulty at all to hear a difference between *wurden* and *würden*. It is rather a problem of native speakers of English. Vice versa, as you know, native speakers of German often have a hard time discerning (and correctly pronouncing) English w and v as in *what* and *vice*. The way to go is: practicing.

Comment: I very much doubt a teacher could grade you badly for your better pronunciation. However you might not want to explicitly  correct her. My brother (a native speaker) once took German class to secure an easy ace. His teacher  had studied in Baden-Württemberg, where some people pronounce ‚hast‘ as ‚hascht‘. She started to ask ‚Hascht Du...‘ and my brother exclaimed ‚ich hasche nicht‘, which can mean both ‚I don’t smoke weed‘ and ‚I don’t attempt to  catch‘. And there went the ace...;)

Answer (score 2):

"ü" and "u" are pronounced differently. You need to find a German-speaker (or a recording) to hear the difference. Here's a link to some examples (but not very good quality) https://de.forvo.com/search/w%c3%bcrden/

Comment: Thanks, I see the difference in pronunciation now, but do you know why my teacher might pronounce it incorrectly, despite having a degree?

Comment: Maybe he hasn't spoken the language enough, or maybe he had bad teachers as well

Comment: What do you suggest I do when it'll come to a speaking assessment?

Comment: Try to it better than your teacher

Comment: Will he mark me wrong though, as I'll be pronouncing what he thinks is the wrong word, as he pronounces werden like würden as well as würden like wurden?

Comment: Since I don't know your teacher and whether he knows the difference, I have no idea how he'll grade you. Do you want to learn good German, or do you just want a good grade?

Comment: Well, both to be honest

Comment: I guess the reason is that the u-umlaut sound does not exist in English and it is not so easy to build. I remember an Irish exchange student, who told me how he learnt to build this sound: "try to speak u (like in moon) and i (like in meat) at the same time" It works :-) and might be a hint for your teacher.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.dict.cc/?s=w%C3%BCrden
Just klick at the speaker button and you can hear how words sound in german and english.